# Request info on 12/48v PSU

Tags: power-supply

I've got a power supply unit from a defunct/decommissioned Satellite Internet setup, and I'm hoping to get clarification on some of the markings on the label.

In the following picture, there's four pin numbers, followed underneath of pins 1 and 2 both volts and max amps, and pins 3 and 4 simply "RETURN".

My question is whether I'm reading the label correctly. (Technically, I've got a few questions here).

Does max(A) under pin 1 mean that at 12v I've got 2.99A available, and at the 48v pin, I've got a max of 0.82A?

Also, when pins 3 and 4 are reflected as return, I'm assuming that means ground, yes?

I'll summarize my questions here to consolidate:

1. Is pin 1 +12v @ 2.99A?
2. Is pin 2 +48v @ 0.82A?
3. Are pins 3 and 4 ground pins, that could (and potentially should) be wired together if both pin 1 and 2 are in use simultaneously?

Here's the pic of the label of the power supply in question:

[image]

Comment: To me it seems your interpretation of the label is correct.

Comment: @K.S. I thought so. It appears obvious, but I thought I'd ask the experts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation of the label is correct as far as I can tell.

Note also that \$12\ \mathrm{V}·2.99\ \mathrm{A} + 48\ \mathrm{V}·0.82\ \mathrm{A} = 75.24\ \mathrm{W}\$, in agreement with the 75 W power rating. This, combined with how simple this interpretation of the markings is, is sufficient evidence for me to say with confidence that you are correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAZUIe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>